# Update Markers without refreshing entire MAP/Page

Tags: javascript, php

Ok so I got this.

```
<?php

                $json_pos = file_get_contents("C:\Users\KLAUS\Desktop\New\This SAMP\scriptfiles\positions.json");
            ?>

            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>

                    <title>SA:MP live map</title>
                    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
                    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
                    <style type="text/css">
                        #map-canvas { display: inline-block; height: 800px; width: 800px; }
                        #map-legend { padding: 10px; background-color: rgba(141, 142, 127, 0.46);}
                    </style>
                </head>

                <body>
                    <div id="map-canvas"></div>

                    <script src="js/SanMap.min.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">


                        // POISION DATA

                        var p_pos = <?php echo (empty($json_pos)) ? "" : $json_pos ?>;




                        // MAP TYPE

                        var mapType = new SanMapType(0, 1, function (zoom, x, y) {
                            return x == -1 && y == -1 
                            ? "images/tiles/map.outer.png" 
                            : "images/tiles/map." + zoom + "." + x + "." + y + ".png";//Where the tiles are located
                        });

                        // SAT TYPE

                        var satType = new SanMapType(0, 3, function (zoom, x, y) {
                            return x == -1 && y == -1 
                            ? null 
                            : "images/tiles/sat." + zoom + "." + x + "." + y + ".png";//Where the tiles are located
                        });

                        // CREATE MAP

                        var map = SanMap.createMap(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), 
                            {'Map': mapType, 'Satellite': satType}, 2, SanMap.getLatLngFromPos(0,0), false, 'Satellite');

                        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(document.getElementById('map-legend'));


                        // IF ONLINE THEN DO FUNCTION CREATE MARKER

                        if(p_pos !== "")
                        {
                            for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(p_pos).length; i++) 
                            {
                                if(p_pos[i].online == 1) createMarker(i);
                            }
                        }










                    // MAKRER FUNCTION

                        function createMarker(id)
                        {




                            var p_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: SanMap.getLatLngFromPos(p_pos[id].x, p_pos[id].y),
                                map: map,
                                icon: "images/marker.png"
                            });


                        }

                            function updateMarker(id)
                        {
                            p_marker.setMap(null);
                            p_marker.setPosition(SanMap.getLatLngFromPos(p_pos[id].x, p_pos[id].y))

                        }


                        setInterval(function()
                            { "updateMarker" }, 1000);



                    </script>
                </body>
            </html>
```

Using that works but I have to refresh the page to see the updated marker position. What I am trying to do is get the markers to update every second without having to refresh the entire page/map

I added this to the bottom thinking it would make it work

```
    function updateMarker(id)
                        {
                            p_marker.setMap(null);
                            p_marker.setPosition(SanMap.getLatLngFromPos(p_pos[id].x, p_pos[id].y))

                        }


                        setInterval(function()
                            { "updateMarker" }, 1000);
```

So the total page I have now is this

```
                <?php

                $json_pos = file_get_contents("C:\Users\KLAUS\Desktop\New\This SAMP\scriptfiles\positions.json");
            ?>

            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>

                    <title>SA:MP live map</title>
                    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
                    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
                    <style type="text/css">
                        #map-canvas { display: inline-block; height: 800px; width: 800px; }
                        #map-legend { padding: 10px; background-color: rgba(141, 142, 127, 0.46);}
                    </style>
                </head>

                <body>
                    <div id="map-canvas"></div>

                    <script src="js/SanMap.min.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">


                        // POISION DATA

                        var p_pos = <?php echo (empty($json_pos)) ? "" : $json_pos ?>;




                        // MAP TYPE

                        var mapType = new SanMapType(0, 1, function (zoom, x, y) {
                            return x == -1 && y == -1 
                            ? "images/tiles/map.outer.png" 
                            : "images/tiles/map." + zoom + "." + x + "." + y + ".png";//Where the tiles are located
                        });

                        // SAT TYPE

                        var satType = new SanMapType(0, 3, function (zoom, x, y) {
                            return x == -1 && y == -1 
                            ? null 
                            : "images/tiles/sat." + zoom + "." + x + "." + y + ".png";//Where the tiles are located
                        });

                        // CREATE MAP

                        var map = SanMap.createMap(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), 
                            {'Map': mapType, 'Satellite': satType}, 2, SanMap.getLatLngFromPos(0,0), false, 'Satellite');

                        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(document.getElementById('map-legend'));


                        // IF ONLINE THEN DO FUNCTION CREATE MARKER

                        if(p_pos !== "")
                        {
                            for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(p_pos).length; i++) 
                            {
                                if(p_pos[i].online == 1) createMarker(i);
                            }
                        }










                    // MAKRER FUNCTION

                        function createMarker(id)
                        {




                            var p_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: SanMap.getLatLngFromPos(p_pos[id].x, p_pos[id].y),
                                map: map,
                                icon: "images/marker.png"
                            });


                        }

                            function updateMarker(id)
                        {
                            p_marker.setMap(null);
                            p_marker.setPosition(SanMap.getLatLngFromPos(p_pos[id].x, p_pos[id].y))

                        }


                        setInterval(function()
                            { "updateMarker" }, 1000);



                    </script>
                </body>
            </html>
```

But its still the same thing, I have to refresh the page to see the updated marker location.

I am so lost in this. Do I have the right idea? Am I putting these in the wrong order? Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about implementation of `setInterval()` func (you have an error in the syntax)?

Try  `setInterval(updateMarker, 1000);`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Also the main point is to use AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                         setInterval(function(){
                            $.getJSON('C:\Users\KLAUS\Desktop\New\This SAMP\scriptfiles\positions.json', function(data) {
                                //alert(data); //uncomment this for debug
                                p_pos = data;
                                for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(p_pos).length; i++)  updateMarker(i);

                            });
                        }, 1000);
                    });
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

```
     <?php

                $json_pos = file_get_contents("C:\Users\KLAUS\Desktop\New\This SAMP\scriptfiles\positions.json");
            ?>

            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>

                    <title>SA:MP live map</title>
                    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
                    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
                    <style type="text/css">
                        #map-canvas { display: inline-block; height: 800px; width: 800px; }
                        #map-legend { padding: 10px; background-color: rgba(141, 142, 127, 0.46);}
                    </style>
                </head>

                <body>
                    <div id="map-canvas"></div>

                    <script src="js/SanMap.min.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">


                        // POISION DATA

                        var p_pos = <?php echo (empty($json_pos)) ? "" : $json_pos ?>;




                        // MAP TYPE

                        var mapType = new SanMapType(0, 1, function (zoom, x, y) {
                            return x == -1 && y == -1 
                            ? "images/tiles/map.outer.png" 
                            : "images/tiles/map." + zoom + "." + x + "." + y + ".png";//Where the tiles are located
                        });

                        // SAT TYPE

                        var satType = new SanMapType(0, 3, function (zoom, x, y) {
                            return x == -1 && y == -1 
                            ? null 
                            : "images/tiles/sat." + zoom + "." + x + "." + y + ".png";//Where the tiles are located
                        });

                        // CREATE MAP

                        var map = SanMap.createMap(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), 
                            {'Map': mapType, 'Satellite': satType}, 2, SanMap.getLatLngFromPos(0,0), false, 'Satellite');

                        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(document.getElementById('map-legend'));


                        // IF ONLINE THEN DO FUNCTION CREATE MARKER

                        if(p_pos !== "")
                        {
                            for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(p_pos).length; i++) 
                            {
                                if(p_pos[i].online == 1) createMarker(i);
                            }
                        }










                    // MAKRER FUNCTION
 var p_marker = new Array();// just global array of markers
                        function createMarker(id){

                            p_marker[id] = new google.maps.Marker({ // initializing p_marker array of markers
                                position: SanMap.getLatLngFromPos(p_pos[id].x, p_pos[id].y),
                                map: map,
                                icon: "images/marker.png"
                            });


                        }

                            function updateMarker(id, pos){
                            p_marker[id].setMap(null);// now it's global, so we can access it from here
                            p_marker[id].setPosition(SanMap.getLatLngFromPos(pos.x, pos.y))

                        }


                        $(document).ready(function(){
                             setInterval(function(){
                                $.getJSON('C:\Users\KLAUS\Desktop\New\This SAMP\scriptfiles\positions.json', function(data) {
                                    //alert(data); //uncomment this for debug
                                    p_pos = data;
                                    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(p_pos).length; i++)  updateMarker(i, p_pos[i]);

                                });
                            }, 1000);
                        });



                    </script>
                </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Changed it to what you said, Still not updating the marker though until I manually refresh the page

Comment: Also you should use AJAX to get the position. Do use jQuery

Comment: I thought you were gonna use my code? Not write something completely different

Comment: My controller is in the same file man read the start of the code.  $json_pos = file_get_contents("C:\Users\KLAUS\Desktop\New\This SAMP\scriptfiles\positions.json"); thats where my positions are at.

Comment: So much more confusing now.

Comment: Do you update contents of the file positions.json every second?

Comment: Yes I do. I created a new file now aswell named getPos.php and added the code and I changed my setInterval to what you said. Still nothing. Could you possibly skype and help me?

Comment: If you do create a positions.json file via php, you could just echo contents of this file in getPos.php to AJAX call without creatin positions.json. It would be much more easier

Comment: positions.json is not created via php, It is called via php. It is created in pawno. The positions.json file is working just fine, That is not the issue. The issue is ont the main page which is posted above.

Comment: Would you add me on skype and help me?

Comment: The task seems to be not too comlicated: at first you load the page, initializing it with needed value of p_pos variable, then you send AJAX post every second to the php file and get new coordinates after dom content is loaded.

Comment: So can you pls take my page from above and re-write it exactly how you are saying because I do not understand.

Comment: Here's an example of using such method http://labs.jonsuh.com/jquery-ajax-php-json/

Comment: Didn't noticed your comment about positions file. It's not easy to do code without testing, but i'll try to provide the correct answer

Comment: I'm not sure, I thought it was just ID. createMarker(id) works just fine so I assumed that updateMarker(id) would work

Comment: Try to replace your setInterval with the code provided in the last edition of my answer)
Should work fine

Comment: Still not working. Can you please put that code in my code above exactly how things should be arranged? I replaced my setinterval with that one but still have all my same code from above. I still have to refresh the page to update the markers.

Comment: Ok, thats what I did. Still not working. I have to manually refresh the page for the map marker to update.

Comment: That might be because p_marker is undefined. Do you debug your code?

Comment: Try to console.log your json file or uncomment "alert(data);"
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log

Comment: I thought p_marker was defined right here var p_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: SanMap.getLatLngFromPos(p_pos[id].x, p_pos[id].y),
                            map: map,
                            icon: "images/marker.png"
                        }); How should I change the updateMarker function?

Comment: just check if your json loads correctly. if it does, then mistake is in updateMarker func

Comment: when I echo out the $json its returns this {"0":{"name":"Kevin_Jones","online":1,"ping":15,"x":-1557.737792,"y":709.588806},"1":{"online":0},"10":{"online":0},"11":and a ton more just not enough space her to write it. It is correct though.

Comment: Yay!
No, p_marker is a local variable in createMarker func's scope

Comment: Ok, So what do I do from here lol. How should we redo the updateMarker?

Comment: So, you should just find needed markers and update em all one by one

Comment: The easiest way is to flush (clear) the map and recreate the markers

Comment: Look here http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Move-Google-Maps-Markers-Change-Update-Marker-position-on-Google-Maps-without-refreshing.aspx

Comment: yes but how do I do that with my positions I have from $json_pos or p_pos

Comment: You may create an array of markers globally and initialize it into createMarker. I'll show you

Comment: I replaced my code with exactly what you have posted above and still wont work unless I refresh the page lol

Comment: Don't I still need some sort of AJAX to update the markers without refreshing the map?

Comment: OMG! Thats because I didn't pass the p_pos to updateMerker)

Comment: Nope, I still have to manually refresh the page to see the updated marker location

Comment: check if pos var is correct in the func updateMarker (do alert(pos) in its body). 
Also check the p_marker[id] in the same way

Comment: How do I get the alert to work? I put alert(pos) in the body but when I refresh nothing happens no alert or anything. Just the map with the marker.

Comment: Okay. Let's connect via skype?

Comment: Your nickname is TaLeNT?